# Crystal Reports count occurrences of record at group level, subgroup level and sub-subgroup level or detail level

Tags: crystal-reports

Is required developing a report as following:
A number of standard users are issuing various documents.
The users that are issuing documents are required to review all documents issued by each user except those issued by them - please refer to attached/linked picture.

**Question 1**: How to get the number of total documents issued by each user?

**Question 2**: How to get the number of total documents reviewed by each user?

**Question 3**: How to get the number of total documents pending for review for each user?

All these three values must be printed next to the user listed on group header 1.

---

**Group 1**

*User_1*   ----- @formula 1: total number of documents (count of GH2);
         ----------------------------------------------- @formula 2: total number of documents issued by current user; ----------------------------------- --@formula 3: total number of documents reviewed by this user; ----------------------------------------@formula 4: total number of documents pending to be reviewed by this user (exclude documents issued by this user)

**Group 2**

```
 Document_1 (issued by user 3)
```

**Group 3**

Reviewed_By_User_1

Reviewed_By_User_2

Reviewed_By_User_4

Reviewed_By_User_8

Reviewed_By_User_10

**Group 2**

```
 Document_2 (issue by user 2)
```

**Group 3**

Reviewed_By_User_1

Reviewed_By_User_3

Reviewed_By_User_6

Reviewed_By_User_8

Reviewed_By_User_9

**Group 2**

```
 Document_...n (issued by any user 1 to 10)
```

**Group 3**

Reviewed_By_User_1

Reviewed_By_User_3

Reviewed_By_User_6

Reviewed_By_User_8

Reviewed_By_User_9

---------------------- and so on for each of the 10 users

**Group 1**

*User_2* - here the above formulas should display...

**Group 2**

```
 Document_1 (issued by user 3)
```

**Group 3**

Reviewed_By_User_1

Reviewed_By_User_2

Reviewed_By_User_4

Reviewed_By_User_8

Reviewed_By_User_10

**Group 2**

```
 Document_2 (issue by user 2)
```

**Group 3**

Reviewed_By_User_1

Reviewed_By_User_3

Reviewed_By_User_6

Reviewed_By_User_8

Reviewed_By_User_9

---

//

Thank you

[click here to view details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmYU9.jpg)

Comment: Please make it clear what your specific question is, and what you've tried so far. See [ask] for help.

Comment: Make it clear....uts cinfusing